# Connection refused while trying to connect to Kafka in AWS EC2

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I have an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance where it's running zookeeper and kafka. I want to connect to kafka from my computer so I have a Java application where I do the connection using kafka api. When I run the application (from Eclipse) I get the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:484)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:476)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:675)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.connect(SimpleConsumer.scala:49)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOrMakeConnection(SimpleConsumer.scala:186)
at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:79)
at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:43)
```

It seems like this lines are throwing the error:

```
FetchRequest req = new FetchRequest("test", 0, offset, 1000);
ByteBufferMessageSet messageSet = simpleConsumer.fetch(req);
```

Also in the console it says something about log4j. I have the `log4j.properties` file in the instance, with the other kafka configuration files. I don't know if it is what is causing this error or if it is something else from the configuration. I've tried to change `hostname` to my public IP address in `server.properties` and the same with `broker.list` in `producer.properties`.

I'm using kafka 0.7.2 version.

Comment: What make you conclude that the connection is not working ? What is the service server port? Did you try telnet to the port to make sure it is open?   Did you setup the EC2 security group to allow connection from that particular port.

Comment: I get that error where it says connection refused. The default kafka port (9092) is open (used ``netstat -tlnp``) and I can see that port listening and in security group I opened that port.

Comment: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused  , means a few things :  services not started;  secgrp not configured; services reject the connection , etc.  It is important to use netcat  to get the exact message , fix the connectivity before the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. There was a line in my code trying to connect to localhost instead of the instance public IP.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, connecting to kafka in ec2. how are you passing in the cert for connecting ? I'm not sure where I'm having trouble as the client just sits trying to establish a connection but just retries until timeout without any feedbacj